# is there a way to control netty handler work time?

Tags: netty

if my handler costs too much time ,i want it return an error as soon as possible ,but now my handler will work until it is done ,so my client catch too many timeout exception . how can i config my netty server ?
i have tried ReadTimeoutHandler and WriteTimeoutHandler but it doesnot help ? how to use that ?
my code is like this :

```
    p.addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    p.addLast("readTimeoutHandler", new ReadTimeoutHandler(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    p.addLast("writeTimeoutHandler", new WriteTimeoutHandler(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    p.addLast("handler", new myHandler());
```

my handler code like this :

```
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    return "ok";
```

what i want is when one request come , after 1s, my server return "timeout" ,but actually after 5s,it return "ok" , why ? how to resolve it ?

i have set that new ReadTimeoutHandler(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),but why after 5s i catch one read time out exception ???  i should catch it after 1s ,isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You block the Thread so there is no way to get notified before. This is because Netty use this thread to handle all IO of the Channel.

Comment: how to accomplish what i said above ?Maurer  ?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to pass the work performed by the handler to a non-netty thread pool. This would free the I/O thread to process timeout events.

If the handler will only process one task per channel at any given time, then management of the task is relatively easy. If the task can be cancelled then simply cancel it when the timeout occurs. If it cannot be cancelled then set a flag to suppress the response when the timeout occurs.

If the handler needs to process multiple tasks per channel concurrently then you'll need to maintain a list of outstanding tasks and decide which one to cancel when the timeout occurs.

You may also be able to run your handler in a separate event executor.